# Draw a dot on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to draw a dot where the X position is 24 and the Y is 60.

Here's my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gn6ga65/), and it doesn't work. Can someone please help me out here?

```js
var color = '#000000';
 var size = '30px';
 $("body").append(
   $('<div></div>')
   .css('position', 'absolute')
   .css('top', 60 + 'px')
   .css('left', 24 + 'px')
   .css('width', size)
   .css('height', size)
   .css('background-color', color)
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/6gn6ga65/1/. Also note you can simplify your code: http://jsfiddle.net/6gn6ga65/2/

Comment: by the way, you know .css can use object mode: `.css({position: 'absolute', top: 60, left: 24, width: size, height: size, backgroundColor: color})` you don't need to specify `+ 'px'` it will handle that automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure css for this:

```css
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 24px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gn6ga65/3/